# Spring: cannot import library

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

i am new to Spring and went out to learn Spring tutorials from [here](http://www.mkyong.com/tutorials/spring-tutorials/) using Eclipse.

But, in Eclipse i cannot import these two libraries

```
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;

import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
```

I even downloaded the Spring source files from the Spring site, included it in the system library, added it in my project and also in the lib folder of my project but no in vain.

Can you help me out to know where exactly is the problem and suggest me some good Spring tutorials sites please.

Thank you all

**EDIT**

Here is the exception

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
    ApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type
    ClassPathApplicationContext cannot be resolved to a type

    at com.test.App.main(App.java:12)
```

Comment: Did you include the jar, as well as the source? That's what really matters.

Comment: It isn't spring's problem that you can't import their classes in eclipse. Include the jars in your project and then restart eclipse. I suggest reading Spring in Action 3.0. Were you getting any compile errors when you manually import the two classes?

Comment: @PaulBellora yes i did include the jars file and even restarted but to no avail

Comment: @VarunAchar yes i did get compile errors

Comment: @sameer, I had similar problems some time ago. I decided it wasn't worth the bother to fiddle with it all and installed the SpringSource Tool Suite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally got it.  My mistake, i was using jars from the src folder and making it as a user library but the correct way is to use the jars from the **dist** folder.

Thank you guys for your answers. :)

Answer (score 2):

Based on comments:

Your jars haven't been included in the classpath. Hence you're getting the compilation errors.

1. Go to project explorer perspective in eclipse
2. right click on lib folder > Build path > Add to build path.

This will include all jars inside the lib folder to your classpath and you won't get any compilation errors.

By the way. These classes are part of spring-context jar so make sure that's in the lib folder.

Comment: yes, i agree.. but is the lib folder still on the build path? It could've been removed from the build path

Answer (score 1):

Add the dependency of spring-context.
For gradle project.

```
implementation group: 'org.springframework', name: 'spring-context', version: '5.3.6'
```

this solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

Update dependency in your pom.xml file, as below:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Delete `module-info.java` file. It worked for me.